# How can I convert an entire line of input into an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to give integer input to Ruby like this:

```
12 343 12312 12312 123123 231
12 343 12312 12312 123123 243
12 343 12312 12312 123123 2123
```

This whole thing should be taken as a number so that I can sort all of them and if there is any repeating numbers I want to print them.  The whole line should be treated as an integer for comparison with the other lines.  I am not able to take the input into one integer, for each of those lines it gives me 12.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to strip the spaces out and leave just the numbers, so '12 343' becomes '12343'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it all as one number, just use:

```
input.gsub(/\s/,'').to_i
```

If you want an array of ints, use

```
input.split.map{|i| i.to_i}
```

Comment: As best as I can tell, he wants each line as one number.

Comment: My brain stopped trying to parse after 'dem', 'dat', and 'no.'

Answer (score 1):

This will keep accepting lines of input, remove all whitespace, convert it to a number, and add them to an array:

```
numbers = []
STDIN.each_line do |line|
  numbers << line.gsub(/\s+/, '').to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will take each of the numbers individually and print out any duplicates.  To check each line instead of the individual numbers, uncomment the extra line.

```
str = <<STRING
12 343 12312 12312 123123 231
12 343 12312 12312 123123 243
12 343 12312 12312 123123 2123
STRING

nums = str.split(/\s/m).collect {|i| i.to_i}
#nums = str.gsub(/ /,'').collect {|i| i.to_i}

uniq_nums = nums.uniq.sort

uniq_nums.each do |uniq|
  puts uniq if nums.find_all {|num| uniq == num}.length > 1
end
```

Returns:

```
12
343
12312
123123
```

Comment: u didnt understand my question .. !! 
12 231 1231 1231 212 is one whole integer input 
and 
12 231 1231 1231 211 is another input
then i have to sort

Comment: Like I mentioned in my initial post, the commented line of code will read each line of input as a single number.  So, simply uncommenting it will give you the desired behavior.